# Getting HTML response instead of JSON in Postman while running my ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postman

This is `AdminController`:

```
namespace PiistechCourier.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/admin")]
    public class AdminController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("all")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetAllAdmins()
        {
            try
            {
                var data = AdminService.Get();
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new { message = ex.Message });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`AdminService`:

```
namespace BLL.Services
{
    public class AdminService
    {
        public static List<AdminDTO> Get()
        {
            var data = DataAccessFactory.AdminData().Read();

            var cfg = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
            {
                c.CreateMap<Admin, AdminDTO>();
            });

            var mapper = new Mapper(cfg);
            var mapped = mapper.Map<List<AdminDTO>>(data);

            return mapped;
        }

        public static AdminDTO Get(int id)
        {
            var data = DataAccessFactory.AdminData().Read(id);

            var cfg = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
            {
                c.CreateMap<Admin, AdminDTO>();
            });

            var mapper = new Mapper(cfg);
            var mapped = mapper.Map<AdminDTO>(data);

            return mapped;
        }
    }
}
```

`WebApiConfig`:

```
namespace PiistechCourier
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

`RouteConfig`:

```
namespace PiistechCourier
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uejZ3.png)

Everything looks fine as the video I have been watching. The guy in the video did everything fine but my one is not working. In browser it is showing 404 and in postman it keeps showing html

I tried changing format html to JSON. And tried other controller as well but it's the same for every routes. I am expecting JSON value which are Id and Name. 10 rows are seeded in the table.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)